# Privilege escalation using symlink

Tags: privilege-escalation

I am working on a "Hack me" challenge, I have access to apache account in the server, I tried to get root access, I run linpeas.sh script and linpeas didn't find anything special, however, there is a file `/etc/profile.d/modules.csh` which I have write permission on that

However, this file is a symbolic link to another file (Which I don't have access to write on that)

Can I do something with this symlink file? the contents of the symlink file is exactly the same as the file which it points to, what happen if I edit  the contents of symlink file?

and do you have any other idea for privilege escalation? (Note that Linpeas didn't find anything special)

Comment: Do not vandalise your posts

Answer (score 3):

From [man symlink(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/symlink.2.html):

> The permissions of a symbolic link are irrelevant; the ownership
> is ignored when following the link

So no, without write permissions on the file, you may not edit it.

There is also not a "symlink file"; the symlink is just a pointer to another file.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any other idea for privilege escalation?

Comment: kernel exploit!

Comment: @SaniaSadian no, that cannot be answered without knowing basically everything about the target system. There are too many possible ways.